# Audio Continues After repeatActionForever Removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I am no longer in pursuit of this topic not because I have found a solution.  No, I have not.

Comment: Try using [gameLoader.actionCryingAudio copy]

Comment: UGGGGHH...  The zombie keeps crying with copy.

Comment: Could you post gameLoader.actionCryingAudio code. It may relevant.

Comment: Certainly...  I've updated the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to remove the action properly.
First create a variable:

```
@implementation FooClass{
SKSpriteNode *_zombie;
}
```

Assign your object:

```
-(void)createEnemy:(CGPoint)p :(NSInteger)type {
    _zombie = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:zombieTexture];
    SKAction *audioSequence = [SKActionsequence:@[waitAudio,gameLoader.actionCryingAudio]];
    [_zombie runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:audioSequence] withKey:@"zombieCrying"];
}
```

Remove the sound with a call to this method:

```
- (void) stopZombieCrying{
[_zombie removeActionForKey:@"zombieCrying"];
}
```

This of course is only useable if you have an instance variable you can call it on.

Comment: As your code is at the moment your remove isn't called on your instantiated object as that only exists in that method.
You have to assign your variable *zombie to the instance variable or you are calling the stop method to something that wasn't even instantiated.

Comment: I'm afraid that my statement about doing 'many things like removing an action with a key' was there right from the beginning.

Comment: And I can see another problem, if you have declared a local variable or property as SKSpriteNode *zombie; in your class, and calling the stop on that instead of the one in your method you are calling on the worn object. On the other hand if you have a property/variable names SKSNode *_zombie; then you should get a warning saying implicit declaration, you are hiding an instance variable or something similar. I can't remember what xcode says but it's something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
-(void)makeZombieCry:(SKSpriteNode*)zombie
{
    SKAction *waitAudio = [SKAction waitForDuration:waitFloat];
    SKAction *audioSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAudio,gameLoader.actionCryingAudio]];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAudio, audioSequence]];

    [zombie runAction:sequence completion:^{
        [self makeZombieCry:zombie];
    }];
}
```

And then call -makeZombieCry in the -createEnemy method

Comment: Thanks.  But why do I want to split an existing method into three?

Comment: Separate methods just add to a better design. Here you go. I have reduced the number of methods.

Comment: Now the audio part is separated and calls itself upon completion. So, removing the action should work. This has the added benefit of variable wait time between cries.

Comment: 1. Separating a method into two or three is not going to solve a thing. => F  Use of runAction completion is not going to solve a thing. => D  3. Please read the title of the topic.  4. Please leave me alone.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, calm down man. I guess you haven't actually tried to implement this. The point is not the separation of the code into methods, but an alternate way to implement repeatActionForever. I guess you do not have any appreciation for abstraction.